# How to locate .profile file in ns2 path inclusion?

Tags: installation, ns2

I copied ns2 in this location `/home/student/ns2/gnit/`

After installing ns2 I need to copy the path in profile file which is usually in `/home/username/.profile` (if we have ns2 in the folder username0
but in my case I have installed it in a sub folder).

*How to open the profile file and include the path name?*

Answer (score 0):

Very simple : You cannot set a new path for 'ns' :

The executable 'ns' is hard coded to look for it´s libraries in the build location:

Like ns-allinone-2.35/{ lib/**, bin/tcsh8.* }.

Which also means that you can never move an ns-allinone-2.xx to a new location.

By copying to a new location : 'ns' will always search for the lib´s in the original build location.

The old year ~1999 text about adding a *PATH text was meant for a University Computer only : I.e. you had no write permissions to /usr/.
Today we just do : $ cd ns-2.3x/ && sudo make install

( 'make install' will copy the executable 'ns' to /usr/local/bin/.)

-

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)